# Javascript: Best approach for displaying one element of a list

Tags: javascript

What is the better approach?

1. adding multiple DOM elements to a parent node and setting all of them but one to "hidden" (`disply='none'`). On demand set the currently visible element to "hidden" and another one to "visible".
2. Just add one DOM element and on demand change its attributes and content.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Definitely option 1. Messing around with the DOM is never a good idea. We just all do it out of necessity.

The less you change the DOM, the better.

P.S. remember to cache your selectors...